# Could not create type with CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that works in IIS 6 but does not work in IIS 7. To test whether web services work at all, I made a simple web service in my ASMX file, as shown:

```
<%@ WebService Language='c#' Class="DEMOAddNumbers" %>
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
public class DEMOAddNumbers : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public int AddThis(int x, int y)
    {
        int mySum;
        mySum = x + y;
        return mySum;
    }
}
```

This web service works, but when I use CodeBehind and put the code in a DEMOAddNumbers.CS file, it says,

Could not create type 'DEMOAddNumbers'

I have tried various ways to reference DEMOAddNumbers.cs, such as:

```
<%@ WebService Language='c#' Class="DEMOAddNumbers" CodeBehind='DEMOAddNumbers.cs' %>

<%@ WebService Language='c#' Class="DEMOAddNumbers" CodeBehind='~/DEMOAddNumbers.cs' %>
```

Put it in an App_Code directory and then:

```
<%@ WebService Language='c#' Class="DEMOAddNumbers" CodeBehind='~/App_Code/DEMOAddNumbers.cs' %>
```

Still same error message. I'm not using Visual Studio, just straight code. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Jim

Comment: Do you want the entity in a code file, or what?

Comment: Is code file different than CodeBehind? I want the C# code in its own CS file.

Comment: Added answer below. If you want a single file that is serving ASMX, you can't use the CodeBehind="" directive. If you want a pure "code only" implementation of a web service, consider either WCF or WebAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the directive to point to a code behind file. You can then embed the code in the ASMX.

I would recommend adding a namespace and all of the proper attributes to the class, but it should work once you stop having ASP.NET engine look for the code behind file.

Comment: Why can't asp.net find the codebehind file? This is the way it works in IIS 6. I don't want all my code in the ASMX file.

Comment: Added another answer that focuses on how to create a code behind file. In order for ASMX to work with the directive, you have 2 files: ASMX and CS. If you want this in one file, it is the ASMX file, as the ASP.NET engine does not interpret tags in a .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this hand coded or in Visual Studio? Assume hand coding.

1. Create new ASMX file called DEMOAddNumbers.asmx and place this line in it
2. Create new ASMX.CS file called DEMOAddNumbers.asmx.cs and place this in it

   using System;
   using System.Web.Services;
   public class DEMOAddNumbers : WebService
   {
     [WebMethod]
     public int AddThis(int x, int y)
     {
       int mySum;
       mySum = x + y;
       return mySum;
     }
   }

You can't have straight code on ASMX. If you want "straight code" move to WCF.

Comment: What is the line in No. 1 above? I have: <%@ WebService Language='c#' Class="DEMOAddNumbers" CodeBehind='~/DEMOAddNumbers.asmx.cs' %>

Comment: Okay, I gave up. I put all of the code in the ASMX file and the web service works. Why are you so hard to work with, IIS7?